# Scaling guest OS resolution in VMWare Workstation

Tags: windows-10, vmware-workstation

I have try to find answer the question: may I use resolution bigger than maximum resolution i have on the host without the appearance of the side and bottom slider in window guest OS. And how it does make?
Guest OS win 10, host os win 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have VMware Workstation V16 here on a Windows 10 Pro Host machine.

You can set a Guest Machine to have a higher resolution than the host, but you cannot actually make the Guest "bigger" than the host, so you will have scroll bars to be able to see all parts of the guest machine.

You can possibly hide scroll bars temporarily by using Full Screen but I am not entirely sure about this.  For sure, to manage the Guest display at any point you must use the scroll bars.

You can manage the guest views you have with the VMware Menu: Fit Guest and Fit Window.

[image]

Within the Guest (Windows or Linux), you can use the Guest Desktop Resolution Controls. The resolution range in my Guests (Windows and Linux) range from bigger than the host to very low.

[image]

Here is an example of a Guest very high resolution. It certainly works but scroll bars result so that you can manage the guest. If there were not scroll bars you would have no practical way of seeing all the parts.

[image]

You can try Full Screen to temporarily not see scroll bars, but ultimately scroll bars will be there to manage the guest.

You can also see in the first screen shot here, no scroll bars. That is accomplished by having Guest resolution less than (not greater than) the Host screen size. This works best for me.